# Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6

Tags: ruby, react-native

When I try to create a project at that time I am getting this error :-

**error Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6**

to create a project

Comment: Short answer, you are running Ruby 3.0.0 on your machine, but the application expects you to run Ruby 2.7.6. Usually I suggest using a Ruby version manager (like [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), [`RVM`](https://rvm.io/) or [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) that allow to install multiple Ruby versions at the same time and switch between them. How did you install your current version of Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Try manually changing the specified version ('2.7.6') to '3.0.0' in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

You need to your check global version path
then use rnv /rbenv to install and defualt new version
after that change its path values from .bash_profile